# Capturing native exceptions in Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, exception

I've got a Cordova/PhoneGap + JQueryMobile application running on iOS and a few customers are reporting that the app is just "vanishing" on them during certain interaction points.

Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce it, so I'm kind of stuck.  I'm wagering that the app is running out of memory or maybe hitting some other kind of iOS level exception.

What I'm wondering is this - does anyone have any suggestions on a good way to capture native exceptions in PhoneGap and either log them or trigger a crash report that the user can email to us?  Until we can see what the crash is being triggered by, there is no hope of fixing it.